# Storing Schedule in Database

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, database-design, scheduling

How do i store routine or schedule in Database in efficient way.Such as i have 20 rooms and in this rooms 8-10,10-12,... this way classes are held.How do i store this sort of schedule in database in efficient way?

Comment: I recently provided an Oracle solution to a simelar general database design question, using three tables. Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193227/what-is-the-best-way-to-optimize-schema-for-capturing-attendance-data/3194711#3194711

Answer (score 2):

```
room
--------------
id INT PK<------------
[more data like]     |
room INT/VARCHAR     |
seats INT            |
                 Foreign Key
room_schedule        |
---------------      |
id INT PK            |
room_id INT<----------
start DATETIME
end DATETIME
```

You can now eaisly attach certain times to a specific room. To have the start/end in a databasespecific format allows you to transform it in other display of the time.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requironments eg reporting, leagal and so on.

For an introduction to this problem see [Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/people/rts/tdbbook.pdf) (Snodgrass) and [Temporal patterns](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/timeNarrative.html) (Fowler)

This can be done with graph databases also, see neo4j example [Time-Based Versioned Graphs](http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?608bf0701e3306a23e77)

Answer (score 0):

I would have two tables: Rooms and RoomSchedule.

RoomSchedule
(ID int primary key,
 RoomID int /*foreign key to rooms*/,
 From int,
 To int
)

This will allow you to easily check for availability and conflicts, later on, and produce reports.

Answer (score 0):

One table for the rooms with their properties.
One table for the bookings, with their properties.

Simple normalization.